# Checking if any of several globs is matched in shell

Tags: shell, if-statement

I've troubles to understand an if syntax of a line in shell:

```
if [ ! -f *file1.txt* -a ! -f *file2.txt* -a ! -f *file3.txt* ]; then
    sbatch file.sh
fi
```

The * is used because my files are backed up to #file.txt.1# format.

As far as I know, the ! creates a 'if not', the -f 'if the string is a file' but I haven't found any function for the -a flag.

I want to submit the file.sh only if all these files are NOT present.

Does anyone could help?

Comment: [`-a` is "and"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) and you cannot use globs with `-f` like that. It does not work if more than one file matches the glob.

Comment: (also, as you'll see if you read Etan's link, using `-a` is deprecated in favor of using `&&` or other operators to chain subsequent `test` invocations).

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explanation. My problem is I cant test it down since I am running stuff in national supercomputers. Could I just write #file.txt.1# or do I need to use \#file.txt.1.#?

Comment: `"#file.txt.1#"` would be my preference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy implementation, compatible with any POSIX shell:

```
exists_any() {
  while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; do   # as long as we have command-line arguments...
    [ -e "$1" ] && return 0  # if first argument names a file that exists, success
    shift                    # remove first argument from the list
  done
  return 1                   # nothing matched; report failure
}

if ! exists_any *file1.txt* *file2.txt* *file3.txt*; then
  sbatch file.txt
fi
```